# PM2 - How to exclude files changes, and watch for service failures only using the --watch flag

Tags: pm2

I have a service which sometimes get some memory leaks from some unknown reason (still investigating).

In the meanwhile to avoid from manually restart the service anytime it goes down I found the option of using `--watch` flag for that.

**The problem**

Using the `--watch` is also watching for file changes, therfore log files are trigger the watch action and the service restarts on any log change, or new files created.

I'm looking for a way to exclude all files from any type and using the watch option only for watching if the service is down, so it will restart it automatically.

Comment: I found an explanation about `--exp-backoff-restart-delay=100`. I' not sure if it will do the autorestart in case of crash, but I'll let you know if it works.